# On the signal recovery in OFDM after estimation

Tags: estimation, ofdm, equalization

Given a modulated signal `X` which is transmitted based on OFDM with `N = 256` sub-carriers through channel `h = [0.7 0.3 0 0 0 0.4]` of length `L = 6;` following the steps : `[X --> ifft(X,N) --> adding CP --> ... ext]` and then we have `Y` representing the received signal representing the output of `FFT` at receiver as below :

`X` = The modulated signal of length 256;

`h` = The channel of length 6;

`Y` = the received signal after taking the `FFT` of length `256` too.

Assuming the channel is estimated at receiver perfectly and `h_est' = [0.7 0.3 0 0 0 0.4];`

I's asking how can we get the sign `X_est` back ? Is it by `X_est = Y. / fft(h_est, 256);`    however when I try that way in Matlab, it doesn't give the estimated transmitted signal !

her is the code as reference:

```
clear; close all; clc

n_subc = 2^8;                          % # of subcarriers
n_ofdm_sym = 1;                        % # of OFDM symbols
n_data_sym = n_subc*n_ofdm_sym;         % # of data symbols to transmit
CP = n_subc/4;                          % CP length                       

M = 4;                                  %Modulation order setting

%Set channel 
h = [0.7 0.5 0 0 0 0.2]; 

iter = 10^2;    %% Iteration
FFT = dftmtx(n_subc);           %% FFT matrix 

SNR = [0:2:40];

for i = 1:length(SNR)
    i
    for j = 1:iter                                % Monte Carlo iterations

    d_symb = randi([0 3],1,n_data_sym);            %generate the data to transmit
    x_mod=qammod(d_symb,M) / sqrt(2);           %modulate

    x_mod_s2p = reshape(x_mod,n_subc,[]);        % serial to parallel

    x_ifft = FFT'*x_mod_s2p;             %Ifft conversion 

     x_cp = [x_ifft(end-CP+1:end,:); x_ifft];     % add CP

    x_ifft_p2s = reshape(x_cp,1,[]);             % parallel to serial


    % --------------------> Channel mixing and adding noise
    y = conv(x_ifft_p2s,h,'same');                          % Linear convolution
   % y = awgn(y,SNR(i),'measured');                          % add noise
    % --------------------> Receiver

    y_s2p = reshape(y,n_subc+CP,[]);             % serial to parallel conversion

    y_cp = y_s2p(CP+1:end,:);                    % Removing CP

    y_fft = FFT*y_cp;                            % FFT

    y_p2s = reshape(y_fft,1,[]);                 % Parallel to serial

    X_est = y_p2s ./ fft(h,n_subc);                                    
    y_demod= qamdemod(X_est,M);


    [~,ber(j)] = biterr(d_symb,y_demod);
    end
    BER(i)=mean(ber);
end

figure
semilogy(SNR,BER)
```

Comment: This gives you the soft information estimates. You need to de-map them to the modulation scheme you used at the transmitter. For example, if you used BPSK, you can de-map the received samples as `X_est > 0`, which will give you a sequence of zeros and ones: zeros when X_est < 0, and 1 otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for you feedback   Could you please re check it ? I get completely different signal !!

Comment: Try first with BPSK and see if it works. If it does, then all you need to do is to read more how to de-map your signals. There are plenty of resources on the Internet about this. It should be straightforward if you understand it theoretically and conceptually.

Comment: sorry I modified the comments at same time you replied,  I get completely different signal !!  maybe there is something I need to modify !!

Comment: Can you paste your code?

Comment: @BlackMath  I added the code into the question,   I tried to write comment for every line to make it easy to understand.   thanks again.

Comment: @Gze the easiest way to check your code is not adding noise. I mean try removing the line `y = awgn(y,SNR(i),'measured');`

Comment: The first thing I noticed is that you define SNR in dB scale, and used it in dB scale. You need to convert it to the linear scale before using it in the code.

Comment: @AlexTP I already tried that way too.  I modified the code without noise !  I still get completely different signal

Comment: @BlackMath you mean the use SNR when adding the noise? ... I already removed the noise but still something wrong happen? I've doubt that conv in that way is not right, maybe I should do convolution of each sub-carrier with channel taps, but that's not logic to me,

Comment: See this post http://www.dsplog.com/2008/08/26/ofdm-rayleigh-channel-ber-bpsk/ and this code http://www.dsplog.com/db-install/wp-content/uploads/2008/08/script_ber_bpsk_ofdm_rayleigh_channel.m and compare it to yours.

Comment: @BlackMath I have checked the code before, yes when estimating the channel based on pilots in frequency domain directly,  it's OK.  but the issue i'm facing is  if i need to recover the signal based on my original channel as described in the question.

Comment: There is no channel estimation in the code, though. So, it should be the same.

Comment: @BlackMath ， exactly, that's what we expect , BUT the problem that  I don't find that !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a mistake int the conv function which you are using in your code. In ofdm, the channel must be convoluted with every symbol. 
the link provided in the above comments are ok, but you need to modify them according to your parameters.  so replace the command of `y = conv(x_ifft_p2s,h,'same');` by below command:

```
for jj = 1 : n_ofdm_sym
         y(jj,:) = conv(h(jj,:),x_cp(jj,:));       
end
```

then add the noise into y.

NP: be careful if the n_ofdm_sym  is more than one, you need to build your channel $h$ as a matrix of size $nofdmsym$ x $nsubc$ .

Good luck

Comment: Thank you,  That worked well !!